# Получение изображения JTextPane без JFrame.pack()

Tags: java, изображения, jframe

Необходимо получить изображение текстового редактора JTextPane без вывода пользователю.
То есть пользователь вводит текст, я сохраняю изображение.
Проблема заключается в том, что мне нельзя использовать JFrame, код будет выполняться на сервере.
А без него выводится черный квадрат...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TestSize
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String trxt =
                "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
                + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
                + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
                + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
                + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
                + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
                + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>";
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setText(trxt);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(boxLayout);
        panel.add(textPane);
        Dimension dimension = panel.getSize();
        System.out.println(dimension);
        dimension = boxLayout.maximumLayoutSize(panel);
        System.out.println(dimension);
        dimension = boxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(panel);
        textPane.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        textPane.setMaximumSize(dimension);
        textPane.setMinimumSize(dimension);
        panel.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        panel.setMaximumSize(dimension);
        panel.setMinimumSize(dimension);
        System.out.println(dimension);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(dimension.width,     dimension.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        //
//        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//        frame.add(panel);
//        frame.pack();
//        frame.dispose();
        //
        panel.paint(graphics);
        graphics.dispose();
        //
        JFrame frameForView = new JFrame();
        frameForView.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameForView.setSize(dimension);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        panel1.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        frameForView.add(panel1);
        frameForView.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Если убрать комментарий:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.dispose();
```

показывает что нужно.

Не могу найти решение вопроса.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");

    String trxt =
            "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
            + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
            + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
            + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
            + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
            + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>\n"
            + "<p>Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест Это тест</p>";
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane.setText(trxt);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    panel.setLayout(boxLayout);
    panel.add(textPane);

    final int width = 640;
    final int height = 480;
    panel.setSize( width, height );
    panel.doLayout();

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );

    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    try {
        panel.paint( g );
    } finally {
        g.dispose();
    }

    ImageIO.write( img, "png", new File( "c:/tmp/panel.png" ) );
}
```

Размер панели нужно задавать явно через `setSize(..)`, после чего вызвать `doLayout()`, чтобы layout manager разложил внутренние компоненты панели.

Если нужно вывести только `JTextArea`, то без панели можно обойтись, задать размер непосредственно полю и вызвать `paint(..)` у него.

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо! То что нужно! Немного видоизменил, чтоб панель получалась по размеру текста:         Dimension dimension = panel.getPreferredSize();
        final int width = dimension.width;
        final int height = dimension.height;
                
        panel.setSize(dimension);